# using method in Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using ViewPager.

in Activity in onBackPressed() method I want to implement saving of my ScrollView's position.
So in a Fragment class I made methods that returns pageNumber of the page that is selected and and another method that returns a getScrollY() position of ScrollView.

But how can I use this method from parent Activity?

I learned that I can use findFragmentById() but what Id does it have ? the R.id of a viewpager? Please explain

here's where the Instance is used :

```
 @Override
              public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return BookPageFragment.newInstance(position);
              }
```

Comment: do you have many fragments or only a few? What kind of PagerAdapter do you use for your ViewPager?

Comment: I have PagerAdapter that extends BaseAdapter, but I do everything in a Fragment class which inflates different kind of views for every page. So, I need to call a method in this fragment from an Activity

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two ways,

If you have created instance of Fragment in activity the you can access method by fragment instance.

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
frag.MyMethodInFragment(); //this method must not be private
```

Or you can also find fragment by tag

```
final String tag = MyFragment.TAG;
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
final Fragment fragFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
if (fragFragment != null) {
    frag = (MyFragment) fragFragment ;
    frag.MyMethodInFragment();
}
```

Note: you have to set tag for your fragment before finding fragment by tag.

I think if you are using ViewPager you can use 1st method easily

**Update**

```
    BookPageFragment b = BookPageFragment.newInstance(position);
    b.CallYourMethod();
return b;
```

Comment: I edited - there is the method in  ViewPager that sets a new instance of Fragment. how can I modify it to access it as you shown in 1st method?

Comment: thank you. now I 'v to figure out why onBackPressed doesn't react in Activity when using ViewPager